# Why the 'i' option of the docker start command does possible display a command's output?

Tags: docker

About Docker if is executed the following command

```
docker run --name ubuntu-it -it ubuntu
```

The container named `ubuntu-it`, based on the `ubuntu` image, is created, run, is offered a `tty` and finally remains running. It can be stopped with the `exit` command. Here the importance about the `it` option to let have a shell available for human interaction.

For experimental purposes, if is executed the following command

```
docker run --name ubuntu-a ubuntu ls
```

The container named `ubuntu-a`, based on the `ubuntu` image, is created, run, is listed/displayed the execution of the `ls` command and finally the container is stopped.

If is need it re-run the `ubuntu-a` container is mandatory use the `docker start` command.

If is executed:

```
docker start ubuntu-a
```

Nothing is shown in the `tty`. According with the official documentation for the [docker start](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/start/) command about its options it indicates:

> **-a, --attach**      Attach STDOUT/STDERR and forward signals

> **-i, --interactive**     Attach container's STDIN

Therefore if is executed:

```
docker start -a ubuntu-a
```

Is possible run again the container and the output of the `ls` command is listed/displayed, it because the current `tty` is *attached* with the `STDOUT/STDERR` stream(s) of the container. Until all is clear.

**The reason of this post**. If is executed (observe now is the `i` option):

```
docker start -i ubuntu-a
```

Is possible run again the container **and** the output of the `ls` command is listed/displayed **too**. Why happens this if the `i` option is based on the `STDIN` stream?